# How do I use StingComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase and Contains() to find substrings in datatables?

Tags: c#, string, arguments, compare, string-comparison

I'm trying to find specific substrings in certain columns of a datatable and I want to ignore case. I'm trying to use contains and StringCompare to achieve this and from what I can tell I'm doing it right, but I get the error:

> The type arguments for method
> 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
> TSource, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer)'
> cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
> explicitly.

I've tried a few things you can see below, and I'm crawling the rest of this site for any help but nothing seems to be working. I'm new to c# any help would be appreciated.

```
DataTable everything  = this.Outputs.Results.GetTable();
DataTable trueMatches = new DataTable();
Plan.Variables.HoldCount = everything.Rows.Count;
Plan.Variables.LotFound = 0;

if (Plan.Variables.HoldCount > 0){
    Plan.Variables.LotFound = 1;
    everything.AcceptChanges();
    
    //foreach (DataRow row in everything.Rows){
    for (int i = 0; i < everything.Rows.Count - 1; i++){
        //string hD = row["HOLD_BRIEF_DESCR"].ToString();
        //string rD = row["RELEASE_BRIEF_DESCR"].ToString();
        string hD = everything.Rows[i][20].ToString();
        string rD = everything.Rows[i][23].ToString();
        
        //something wrong with StingComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, code compiles if removed
        if (hD.Contains("cube", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || 
            hD.Contains("cubing", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
            hD.Contains("cubed", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
            rD.Contains("cube", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
            rD.Contains("cubing", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
            rD.Contains("cubed", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){
                trueMatches.Rows.Add(row);
                row.Delete();
            }
    }
    everything.AcceptChanges();
    trueMatches.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Comment: Are you using .net framework? If yes, it doesn't have the overload for StringComparison - you will have to use `IndexOf` instead `hD.IndexOf("cube", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0`

Comment: It got introduced in .net core 2.1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-2.1 but is missing .net framework: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8.1 (at top left of the page you will find a drop down with the version of .net framework/.net core/.net)

Comment: Rand Random, thanks this worked. I don't know much about .net but I guess I am using it. Are there any good sources to learn a quick and dirty overview of .net>

Comment: when you are writing a c# application you will always use one of those .net framework, .net core, .net or mono - those are the necessary "frameworks" to write any c# application they all have advantages and disadvantages - the most recent and IMHO most activ developed is .net - the latest version of .net is 7 - notice that .net core is the old name of .net so any net core version smaller or equal to 3.x is a predecessor of .net they changed the name and dropped the "core" part - you may consider porting to .net 7 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/ -

Answer (score 0):

.net doesn't provide `Contains` with `StringComparison` argument. As a quick
solution you can use `IndexOf`

```
hd.IndexOf("cube", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
```

Or

```
using System.Linq;

...

string[] words = new string[] {
  "cube", "cubing", "cubed",
};

// note i < everything.Rows.Count - we should not subtract 1
for (int i = 0; i < everything.Rows.Count; ++i) {
  if (words.Any(word => hD.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ||
      words.Any(word => rD.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) {
    //TODO: what is row here? If it's everything.Rows[i] see the code below
    trueMatches.Rows.Add(row);
    row.Delete();
  }
}
...
```

There's a possible issue with `row`, if it's `everything.Rows[i]` the loop should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < everything.Rows.Count;) {
  if (words.Any(word => hD.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ||
      words.Any(word => rD.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) {
    //TODO: what is row here? If it's everything.Rows[i] see the code below
    var row = trueMatches.Rows[i]; 
    row.Delete();

    trueMatches.Rows.Add(row);
  }
  else
    ++i;
}
```